# Object of type "" is not JSON serializable

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create an API and pass the context data in Response but I am getting the error:

> Object of type TakenQuiz is not JSON serializable

Below is the code:

```
taken_quizzes = quiz.taken_quizzes.select_related('supplier__user').order_by('-date')
total_taken_quizzes = taken_quizzes.count()
quiz_score = quiz.taken_quizzes.aggregate(average_score=Avg('score'))
least_bid = quiz.taken_quizzes.aggregate(least_bid=Min('least_bid'))

extra_context = {'taken_quizzes': taken_quizzes, 
'total_taken_quizzes': total_taken_quizzes,
'quiz_score': quiz_score, 'least_bid': least_bid, 'matching_bids': matching_bids,
'driver_num': driver_num, 'lat_lon_orig': lat_lon_orig, 'lat_lon_dest': lat_lon_dest,
'user_pass': user_pass, 'username': username, 'password': password, }


print("extra content is ", extra_context)

return Response(extra_context)
```

Here is the context data:

```
extra content is  {'taken_quizzes': <QuerySet [<TakenQuiz: TakenQuiz object (1)>]>, 'total_taken_quizzes': 1, 'quiz_score': {'average_score': 0.0}, 'least_bid': {'least_bid': 899}, 'matching_bids': [], 'driver_
num': 0, 'lat_lon_orig': '36.1629343, -95.9913076', 'lat_lon_dest': '36.1629343, -95.9913076', 'user_pass': ('jkcekc', 'efce'), 'username': 'efw', 'password': 'sdf'}
```

The error I believe is because of the queryset in the extra_context, How do I resolve this ?
I tried json.dumps but it still doesn't work

Serializer.py

```
class takenquizSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TakenQuiz
        fields = "__all__"
```

Models.py

```
class TakenQuiz(models.Model):
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='taken_quizzes')
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='taken_quizzes')
    score = models.FloatField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    least_bid = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    confirmed = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='Not Confirmed')
```

**UPDATE**

```
taken_quizzes = quiz.taken_quizzes.select_related('supplier__user').order_by('-date')
taken_quizzs = takenquizSerializer(taken_quizzes).data
```

Comment: Well, what do you want to happen? json.dumps doesn't know what a queryset is, you have to give it things it understands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to serialize taken_quizzes objects either via some serializer or calling 
".values()" and specifying the required key, if any (otherwise it will give all values of the model as a dictionary)

```
{
    'taken_quizes': TakenQuizSerializer(taken_quizzes, many=True).data,
    # or
    'taken_quizzes': taken_quizzes.values(),
    ....
}
```

Comment: I created a new serializer with fields = "__all__" but when i use this it says: `AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `score` on serializer `takenquizSerializer`.` But I have score in my model as well as queryset

Comment: I added serializer as well as model.py for better understanding

Comment: Please update the code (where you have used this serializer) as well.

Comment: Please have a look now

Comment: The error does'nt seem to be relating to the issue i am observing but please give it a try. `takenquizSerializer(taken_quizzes, many=True).data` a serializer usually serializes a single object, but you are passing a queryset to a serializer.

Comment: i did that a while ago and it's back to `Object of type TakenQuiz is not JSON serializable`

Comment: try calling serializer directly inside the extra_content dictionary `extra_content = { 'taken_quizzes': takenquizSerializer(taken_quizzes, many=True).data, ... }` I believe you might be using the wrong variable as their names resemble a lot.

Answer (score 1):

as ruhaib mentioned you need to serialize the data. If i dont want to define special serializers for models this is what I do.

```
    from django.core import serializers

    taken_quizzes=....
    data=serializers.serialize('json',taken_quizzes)
```

you can do this before you populate extra_content with some data.

Comment: It says `module 'rest_framework.serializers' has no attribute 'serialize'`

Comment: That's because you are calling 'serializers' from rest_framework. you should use serializers from django.core